# How to look for functions in numpy and regular python

Tags: python, numpy

I have seemed to forgot the command to look for functions in python and in numpy? Are there shortcuts that one can use to search for functions in numpy and python? I know help is used assuming you know the name of the function. Is the function lookfor?

Comment: you mean `dir(some_module)`? ... google is usually what I use though :P

Comment: With IPython, you can type (e.g.) `sys.` <TAB> to see the contents of the `sys` module.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `help()` and/or `dir()`. Try:

```
import os

help(os)
```

and:

```
dir(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [9]: import numpy as np

In [10]: dir(np)[-10:]
Out[10]:
['vectorize',
 'version',
 'void',
 'void0',
 'vsplit',
 'vstack',
 'where',
 'who',
 'zeros',
 'zeros_like']
```